# How do I use wmctrl to detect if a window is present?

Tags: gnome, xdotool, wmctrl

I am doing some UI automation and I want to perform some task based on the window being present. The window only opens up in same cases. The command that I want to use is:

```
wmctrl -a "Confirm New Extension"; xdotool key Left space
```

but I want to execute the `xdotool` command only if there is a new window called "Confirm New Extension". I'm not sure if wmctrl returns anything to do something like

```
if [ wmctrl -a "Confirm New Extension" ]; then
    xdotool key Left space
fi
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

After a little experimenting I was able to manage it using the following script:

```
if test $(wmctrl -l | grep "Confirm New Extension" 2>&1 | wc -l) -eq 1; then 
    wmctrl -vxa "Confirm New Extension"
    xdotool key Left space 
fi
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: thanks man. this is also useful for xdotool on waiting window to open

Comment: @JastriaRahmat To wait for a window to open, you can use `xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --name 'window title regexp'` (`--sync` makes it wait)